# Keep getting access forbidden by rule error to /app/etc/local.xml

Tags: magento, nginx

I'm using nginx as the web server. In error.log, I always see this error message every time it is accessed:

```
2015/04/30 13:22:16 [error] 3278#0: *26954 access forbidden by rule, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.82, server: www.example.com, request: "POST /app/etc/local.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com"
```

The IP address is my own server's IP address. The only line I saw in nginx.conf is:

```
location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
```

Although it's good to know that /app/etc/local.xml is inaccessible as it should be, however, it's quite annoying every time I need to investigate the error.log file. What could be the cause?

Comment: Magento's security **self-check** to make sure that `app/etc/local.xml` is not accessible from the web, hence your server IP address.

Comment: In the access log, at the same time, there is a request from that IP. You can look up which URI is being requested, and use that to figure out why that is being requested and refused. Once you have the request URI, we can help provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

The log entry indicates that some one is trying to make a POST request to your app/etc/local.xml. Since there's a .htaccess under the app directory, this file is inaccessible to be requested. I would report this to your hosting provider, maybe they can identify the IP address of the hacker making this request.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, the IP address is always my own server. And there is no .htaccess since I'm using nginx.

Comment: Maybe your nginx is configured to deny access to app/etc/local.xml.

Comment: @DavidTay - which it is supposed to do, this file contains your MySQL login credentials.